# Where inodes are stored in Unix-like system?

Tags: filesystem, ext4

In Unix-like OS, where the *inodes* info are stored for the exact path of the file. Else from where `df` command are getting inode info as output where that file is located.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could edit the question and add output of `uname -a; lsb_release -a`

Answer (score 1):

The inodes are stored in the partition where the filesystem lives as part of the filesystem meta-data, like in /dev/sda1 or whatever the disk and partition are called.

Exactly where and how they are stored depends on the type of filesystem, ext2|3|4, btrf, ufs, or others.